# Chrome stuck in dark mode even if the system is not in dark mode

Tags: macos, google-chrome, big-sur

My chrome seems to be stuck in dark mode even though the system is not in night mode.

I have already tried the following:

1. Turning it on and off (1st law of fixing something)
2. Changing the System **Preferences > General > Appearance** to `Light`

Chrome: Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (x86_64)
MacOS : Big Sur 11.2.3

Any help is appreciated. I am currently writing this in dark mode and it's annoying

Answer (score 1):

So, after struggling a lot found this flag which was set to enabled.

Open the flag settings in your chrome

[chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark](http://chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark)

Change the value from `enabled` to:

- `default` if you want the dark mode to depend on OS
- `disabled` always light mode